# Preview LaTeX doesn't work when I delete the _region_.prv folder

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex

Suppose I create a latex document in `~/junk/text.tex` with the following conent:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x$
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

I then run `C-c C-p C-b` and preview-latex works as expected.
The folder `_region_.prv` and the files `_region_.log`, `prv_test.fmt`, `prv_test.log` and `_region_.tex` get created (and the folder `auto` as well).
When I delete the folder and those files, preview-latex won't work anymore.
I get the error

```
Running `Preview-LaTeX' on `~/junk/_region_' with ``lualatex  -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error \&prv_test "/AUCTEXINPUT{" _region_.tex "}"''
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) 
 restricted system commands enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt prv_test.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/berber/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/berber/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=prv_test, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: Disabled formats: 6
mktexfmt [INFO]: Not selected formats: 36
mktexfmt [INFO]: Total formats: 42
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
Sorry, I can't find the format `prv_test.fmt'; will try `prv_test.fmt'.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt prv_test.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/berber/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/berber/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=prv_test, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: Disabled formats: 6
mktexfmt [INFO]: Not selected formats: 36
mktexfmt [INFO]: Total formats: 42
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `prv_test.fmt'!

TeX Output exited as expected with code 1 at Mon Jun  3 16:17:28
LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images
```

How can I make preview-latex work again?

Comment: Try renaming the file and/or the containing folder, kill the buffer and reopen the file. It seems something gets cached and screws up subsequent attempts to preview, because it expects the cached image to still be in the _region_.prv directory.

Comment: ... and report it as a bug.

Comment: I have made a bug report @NickD https://debbugs.gnu.org/db/36/36114.html and I have tried what you said.  changing the filename works, but after changing it back then doesn't work...  i have tried this on multiple machines.